# total value with the same keys within multiple dim array of php

Tags: php

I have an array like this:

```
$a = array(
    array('amount'=>10,'curr'=>'USD'),
    array('amount'=>20,'curr'=>'JPY'),
    array('amount'=>30,'curr'=>'BAT'),
    array('amount'=>50,'curr'=>'BAT'),
    array('amount'=>100,'curr'=>'USD')
    );
```

I want to sum all amount the same currency together and return like this:

```
$total = array('BAT'=>80,
              'JPY'=>20,
              'USD'=>110
           )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$total = array();
foreach($a as $arr){
    if(!isset($total[$arr['curr']])){
        $total[$arr['curr']] = 0;
    }
    $total[$arr['curr']] += $arr['amount'];
}
```